# Redirecting from/to GWT application for authentication

Tags: java, authentication, redirect, gwt

I need to perform user authentication of an application using ADFS. The application is a GWT application and I need to redirect the application to ADFS for the authentication to take place. I researched on the internet and somebody suggested to do the authentication outside of GWT and then redirect it to the GWT host URL. This makes sense but I am confused as to how to combine them together into one application.

Also, I tried redirecting from the GWT server code (and then returning to the GWT client after authentication), but getThreadLocalResponse.sendRedirect("{ADFS SERVER URL}") returns failure for the RPC call. And even if it worked, how do I come back to the GWT application?

I am new to GWT and java, on whole. I will be grateful if somebody could guide me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GWT is a client-side technology. The "host page" should be wrapped/delivered via JSP or another robust server-side mechanism. Then it'd work like any other JSP/MVC application, as far as authentication, redirects, etc.